# An approximate measure of the real interest rate applying rule of thumb for growth rates

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate

I don't understand how one can get from:

$1+r_{t+1}$=$\frac{1+i_{t}}{1+\pi_{t+1}}$

to

$1+r_{t+1}$$\approx1+i_{t}-\pi_{t+1}$

by applying the following rule of thumb:

$Z$=$\frac{X\cdot{Y}}{Q}$

implies

$\frac{\Delta{Z}}{Z}$=$\frac{\Delta{X}}{X}$+$\frac{\Delta{Y}}{Y}$-$\frac{\Delta{Q}}{Q}$

Note:

$r_{t+1}$: real interest rate

$i_{t}$: nominal interest rate

$\pi_{t+1}$: inflation rate

I hope someone will help :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Argument 1:

$$ 1+r_{t+1} = \frac{1+i_{t}}{1+\pi_{t+1}}$$

Take the [natural log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) of both sides.

$$ \log(1+r_{t+1}) = \log(1+i_{t}) - \log(1+\pi_{t+1})$$

Observe that $\log(1 + x) \approx x$ for $x$ near zero because that's the [first order taylor expansion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244199/why-is-it-that-natural-log-changes-are-percentage-changes-what-is-about-logs-th/244237#244237). Hence:

$$ r_{t+1} \approx i_{t} - \pi_{t+1}$$

### Argument 2:

$$ 1+r_{t+1} = \frac{1+i_{t}}{1+\pi_{t+1}}$$
$$  1+r_{t+1} + \pi_{t+1} + r_{t+1} \pi_{t+1} = 1+i_{t}$$

And if $r_{t+1} \pi_{t+1}$ is closer to zero

$$ r_{t+1} + \pi_{t+1} \approx i_{t}$$